# Issues with running AVD Emulator

Tags: android, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_27 has terminated. (I've tried for different AVDs)

My log file is here:
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\log

2024-01-17 06:56:35,428 [1330253]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 27 - C:\Users\111\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_5_API_27 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2024-01-17 06:56:35,447 [1330272]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 27 - Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A)
2024-01-17 06:56:35,447 [1330272]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 27 - Found systemPath C:\Users\111\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86
2024-01-17 06:56:35,496 [1330321]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 27 - Ignore IPv6 address: 2808:7692:c501:0:fc:7592:c501:0 (2x)
2024-01-17 06:56:35,497 [1330322]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 27 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\111.android\avd..\avd\Pixel_5_API_27.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-01-17 06:56:40,161 [1334986]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 5 API 27 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-01-17 06:56:40,506 [1335331]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_5_API_27 is online, assuming it's not

I tried to run android emulator, But I got this error.
I want to run android emulator.